# Configure citation-style in footnote and bibliography under jurabib-style

Tags: bibliographies, citing, jurabib

I use the jurabib-package and want to configure the citation-style.

```
\usepackage{jurabib}
\jurabibsetup{authorformat={italic}}
```

The entry in the bibliography is currently (I changed it during the process several times, to achieve the desired output, e.g. with journal and the editors, but it didn't work)

```
@book{MüKo286Ernst,
  title = {Münchener Kommentar zum BGB},
  author = {Ernst},
  year = {2022},
  edition = {9},
}
```

As I want to display more than one cite in one footnote, I figured that I have to use the `\footnote{}`-command in connection with the `\cite{}`:

```
\footnote{\cite[§ 286 Rn. 28]{MüKo286Ernst}.}
```

Unfortunately, the output in the footnote looks like "*Ernst* § 286 Rn. 28." It's a commentary and should look like: "*Ernst* in: MüKo-BGB, § 286 Rn. 28".

The output in the bibliography looks like: "**Ernst:** Münchener Kommentar zum BGB. 9. Auflage. 2022" As it's a commentary it should look like: "Münchener Kommentar zum BGB (next column) Band 2: Schuldrecht Allgemeiner Teil I, herausgegeben von Franz Jürgen Säcker/Roland Rixecker/Hartmut Oetker/Bettina Limperg, 9. Aufl., München 2022 (zit.: Bearbeiter in: MüKo-BGB)".

The tricky business is, that this commentary should appear once in the bibliography, but is named multiple times during the cites in the footnotes (every time with a different author and passage). As I said, I changed the entry in the bibliography several times, but somehow the output looks always not as I want it to.